# Image cropping on white boundaries from a Complex Image using python

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, image-segmentation

**Problem Summary:** I have got many complex histopathology images with different dimensions. Complex means a single image having multiple images in it as shown in below input image examples. I need to separate out or crop each single image only and not the text/label/caption of it from that input complex image and further save each of them individually. For the bounding boxes I have gone through the white boundaries (separation) along the single images.

**Complex Input Image Example 1:**

[image]

**Complex Input Image Example 2:**

[image]

**Complex Input Image Example 3:**

[image]

**Code I have tried:**

```py
import cv2
import numpy as np

# reading the input image
img = cv2.imread('cmp.jpg')
cv2.imshow("histology image", img)

# defining border color
lower = (0, 80, 110)
upper = (0, 120, 150)

# applying thresholding on border color
mask = cv2.inRange(img, lower, upper)
cv2.imshow("masked", mask)

# Using dilate threshold
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (15, 15))
mask = cv2.morphologyEx(mask, cv2.MORPH_DILATE, kernel)

# coloring border to white for other images
img[mask==255] = (255,255,255)
cv2.imshow("white_border", img)

# converting image to grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# applying otsu threshold
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU )[1] 
cv2.imshow("thresholded", thresh)

# applying 'Open' morphological operation
kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (17,17))
morph = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_OPEN, kernel)
morph = 255 - morph
cv2.imshow("morphed", morph)

# finding contours and bounding boxes
bboxes = []
bboxes_img = img.copy()
contours = cv2.findContours(morph, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
for cntr in contours:
    x,y,w,h = cv2.boundingRect(cntr)
    cv2.rectangle(bboxes_img, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 0, 255), 1)
    bboxes.append((x,y,w,h))
cv2.imshow("boundingboxes", bboxes_img)

cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I am not getting exact bounding boxes for each of single images present in the input complex image and further I need to save each cropped image individually. Any kind of help will be much appreciated.

Comment: if it's a PDF, you can scrape the pictures out of there. if it isn't, ask the authors of those papers for their pictures.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz These images are downloaded from papers-open access articles. It's a pdf only and I have got the images as well which are used by authors. Further I need to classify them into disease type using CNN model. But for the complex images first I need to separate out each image individually before sending it to the classifier. My code is not working perfectly. So, what should I do ? Is there any python package or tool to do so ? Please comment or guide me.